# JavaScript file not being read even with correct script src tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to just on some JavaScript practice and my file is not linked or loading with my HTML. I've even just put a regular script tag in my html and did a simple console "Hello World" in it and its not showing up.

I've tried creating a whole new javascript file and still get the error.

Here's the code in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Omifood Hero Section</title>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;600;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      html {
        font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
        color: #444;
      }

      .container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 1200px;
      }

      header {
        /* background-color: orangered; */
        height: 100vh;
        position: relative;

        background-image: linear-gradient(
            rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.6),
            rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.6)
          ),
          url(hero.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        color: #fff;
      }

      nav {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 700;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding-top: 32px;
        /* background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue); */

        /* background-color: green; */
      }

      .header-container {
        width: 1200px;
        position: absolute;

        /* In relation to PARENT size */
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;

        /* In relation to ELEMENT size */
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

        /* background-color: violet; */

        /* text-align: center; */
      }

      .header-container-inner {
        width: 50%;
        /* background-color: blue; */
      }

      h1 {
        font-size: 52px;
        margin-bottom: 32px;
        line-height: 1.05;
      }

      p {
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 1.6;
        margin-bottom: 48px;
      }

      .btn:link,
      .btn:visited {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 600;
        background-color: #e67e22;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 16px 32px;
        border-radius: 9px;
      }

      h2 {
        font-size: 44px;
        margin-bottom: 48px;
      }

      section {
        padding: 96px 0;
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="container">
        <div>LOGO</div>
        <div>NAVIGATION</div>
      </nav>

      <div class="header-container">
        <div class="header-container-inner">
          <h1>A healty meal delivered to your door, every single day</h1>
          <p>
            The smart 365-days-per-year food subscription that will make you eat
            healty algain. Tailored to your personal tastes and nutritional
            needs
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn">Start eating well</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Some random heading</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque quas,
          minus beatae sapiente debitis voluptatum, laudantium veritatis impedit
          corrupti officia recusandae fugit, voluptates iure velit! Ad suscipit
          vitae nobis optio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing
          elit. Reiciendis sequi quam earum voluptas eum laboriosam at
          cupiditate debitis in odio adipisci repudiandae enim ea, sint quos
          similique! Debitis, facilis dolore?
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
    <script>
      console.log(`hello world`);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "still get the error" -- What error?  You haven't mentioned an error.  Remember that doing a simple refresh does not reload the scripts and images.  You need `shift-F5` or `shift-ctrl-R` to force a full refresh.

Comment: What is your folder structure? Try `<script src="js/script.js"></script>`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're hoping we'll do for you. Is the script file inside a folder named `js` which resides alongside the HTML file? What do you see in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools?

Comment: @DoomBot -- that's exactly what he has.

Comment: My bad. I still sometimes mix up `/`, `./` and `../`.

Comment: In the network tab I see all of html and css files, but no javascript file. I'm not really sure whats going on as I've used js before with no issues

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing everything except the bare necessity. Then add each element one by one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 
  </body>
    <script>
      console.log(`hello world`);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You typed `` instead of '' or "", so it didn't show the console.log.
About the JS document, check the folder path.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Omifood Hero Section</title>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;600;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <style>
   
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="container">
        <div style="font-weight: bold; color: gray;">LOGO</div>
        <div style="font-weight: bold; color: gray;">NAVIGATION</div>
      </nav>

      <div class="header-container">
        <div class="header-container-inner">
          <h1>A healty meal delivered to your door, every single day</h1>
          <p>
            The smart 365-days-per-year food subscription that will make you eat
            healty algain. Tailored to your personal tastes and nutritional
            needs
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn">Start eating well</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Some random heading</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque quas,
          minus beatae sapiente debitis voluptatum, laudantium veritatis impedit
          corrupti officia recusandae fugit, voluptates iure velit! Ad suscipit
          vitae nobis optio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing
          elit. Reiciendis sequi quam earum voluptas eum laboriosam at
          cupiditate debitis in odio adipisci repudiandae enim ea, sint quos
          similique! Debitis, facilis dolore?
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
    <script>
      console.log('hello world');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```